# Why doesn't react output anything to the console when input is submited?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events

This is the react code I'm currently using:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export class AddProduct extends Component {
    doSomething(){
        console.log('Hello')
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>Product name</h3>
                <input type="text" id="product"></input>
                <h3>Product price</h3>
                <input type="text" id="price"></input>
                <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" onSubmit={(e) => {this.doSomething();}}></input>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default AddProduct
```

I'm expecting a 'Hello' output to the terminal when the submit button is pressed however it does not show up. Could anyone help me out?

Comment: If you want to fire on submit, you may want to use a proper form element, [checkout these docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html).

Comment: basic of events, submit is fired on the form, not inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to handle a submit event, you must use a `<form />` element.

Example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class AddProduct extends Component {
    doSomething() {
        console.log('Hello')
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={(e) => this.doSomething()}>
                <h3>Product name</h3>
                <input type="text" id="product" />
                <h3>Product price</h3>
                <input type="text" id="price" />
                <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
        );
    }
}

export default AddProduct;
```

[See React Form Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html)

Answer (score 2):

`<input>` elements do not fire a `submit` event when clicked, even when inside a form:

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('submit', () => {
  alert('submit event seen');
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

A click event would work, though. Change

```
onSubmit={(e) => {this.doSomething();}}
```

to

```
onClick={(e) => {this.doSomething();}}
```

If your `<input>` happens to be inside a form, you could attach a `submit` listener to the form instead.